# Make the border image, but with transformation

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a button that is giving me a headache. The client asks me that the border must also be the image. For the box, I can change it perfectly but the effect that the next button has does not allow me to change it.

[image]

If I add border-image to this button, it is applied fine, but the arrow is an after with a deformation and adding the border-image does not work correctly. Can somebody help me?

Website is : https://skyrocketdigitalmarketing.designthatranks.com/header-trial/

Comment: It's not really clear what effect you want.

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
         background-color: #7e7e7e;
     }

        .theme-btn {
            width: 300px;
            height: 50px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 2px solid #ffee02;
            background-color: transparent !important;
            background-image: url(https://skyrocketdigitalmarketing.designthatranks.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Bg-2.png) !important;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            transition: all .2s;
            color: white !important;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
            position: relative;
        }

        .theme-btn::after {
            content: "";
            background: #ff1d1d;
            width: 59px;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: -20px;
            z-index: 0;
            transform: skew(-24deg, 0deg);
            transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
            background-image: url(https://skyrocketdigitalmarketing.designthatranks.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Bg-2.png) !important;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            border: 2px solid #ffee02;
        }

        .theme-btn a {
            color: #ffee02;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        .theme-btn i {
            width: 40px;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 4px;
            z-index: 1;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        .theme-btn i::after {
            content: "";
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            transform: skew(-24deg, 0deg);
            transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
```

```html
<div class="theme-btn">
   <a href="">
      <span>
          Explore Packages 
      </span>
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
   </a>
</div>
```